# Is there any kind/type of bank accounts that does not show me the transaction history of my account?

Tags: bank-account, online-banking

I need to have a bank account for my NGO that can be accessible by anyone. In order to do that I will share my credentials. My problem is, I need no one to be able to see the transaction history of the account, but just the SUM in the account.

The reason I am sharing my bank account has to do with transparency, so everyone can see the sum in the account.

The reason I do not want anyone to see the transaction history is, because I would like the people transferring money to remain anonymous to the rest of the world.

I would surely like to have the ability to see the transaction history, given that I either enter another password for that or using the credit/atm card for example.

If there is another solution achieving the same requirements, I would be happy hearing about that.

Preferably a solution that works in Europe would be great. Optimally a solution that works in Germany is preferred, but if this kind of service is offered else where, it would be also great

Comment: I really do not understand why this is off topic. I searched through the whole stackexchange network and found that this is the best place to ask this question. Guide me somewhere else if there is some better place. I described my situation clearly and got a clear answer. Sadly It was deleted and I can not retrieve the answer. This would have helped me.  To me this does not make any sense. The only way to see the answer if I have 10k Reputation and this is sadly not the case. Now all I ended up with is a hope that I opened the deleted answer in the right time..

Comment: You could have people donate to one account, but transfer the funds to another account that is public. Aggregate the donation amounts into a single weekly (or whatever) transfer.

Comment: Thanks. This is a possibility actually. A better possibility however (more transparent one) would be to see the amount IN the account your transferring to. Does not leave any suspicion. It will be a bit more trustworthy

Comment: In order to avoid the accusation (right or wrong) that the question is off-topic, it might be a good idea to re-word the question so that it is asking for the name of a *class* of financial products/services (e.g. "Is there a *kind* of bank account that has these properties, and what is the name for that kind of bank account?") rather than for specific offerings. In case the name for that class of products varies from country to country, it might also help to mention the countries in which your NGO would be able to open and operate the account.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. I hope the changes of the title are enough to make the moderators reconsider.

Comment: I don't think this is sufficiently related to *personal* finance, given this is not something a *person* would want to do.  This site isn't about corporate finance (or not-for-profit finance).

Comment: Since I'm struggling to see the utility in a zero-lag, on-demand valuation (as opposed to a weekly update value - what happens if there's a fat finger data entry error for a few hours) is there an example of another organization with this feature?  If so, can you call them up for a reference interview and ask how they solved this?

Comment: A weekly update value is no problem at all. I just would like the people to see the amount on the SAME account they transfered the money to, in order to have the transparency of the current sum in the account.

Comment: LOL. "put on hold as off-topic" or "how stackexchange is becoming useless"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is:

- You want strangers to be able to view the balance of your account.
- You want people to be able to donate to the account without strangers being able to know who they are (even if you know who they are).
- You are open to "other solutions" achieving this requirement, besides a conventional bank account.

Have you considered taking donations via a [cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency) such as Bitcoin? Most cryptocurrencies meet all the above criteria.

N.B. The level of anonymity offered by a cryptocurrency transaction varies from pseudonymity to quite strong anonymity, depending upon the cryptocurrency and the way the transaction is performed. You should review the available options to see which (if any) meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will review all the available options here. I would like to have a simple method for people to transfer money to that account. I will research this method and post here if this can be done without complexity to the people who donate.

Comment: Bitcoin transfers are not anonymous. There is a public log that shows the id of the 'wallet' on both ends of any transfer. Depending what other transactions are connected to the donor's wallet it may or may not be easy to tell who they are.

Comment: @bdsl yes, Bitcoin transactions are, IIUC, [pseudonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonymity). They carry a risk of [deanonymisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-anonymization). There are some efforts underway to increase the [privacy properties of Bitcoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bitcoin&oldid=729627297#Privacy). Whether the privacy currently offered by Bitcoin is enough for the OP, I can't say. So, as mentioned in my answer, the OP should review the available options to see which (if any) meet their requirements.