# Transparent way to create a money pool

Tags: cryptocurrency, crowdfunding, funding

Let's say I want to raise money for a project, and I want my investors to know the number of contributions and their amount.
Obviously I can't give my bank or payment processor credentials (psw).
This data must be completely transparent, public, operated by a third-party (can't be cooked up).
My ideas:

- Bitcoin. Ok they are transparent (you can check a wallet's balance), but they are cryptic to the general public.
- Use a Forex broker, because with Metatrader they have an investor account (can see, but not operate).

Any ideas?

Comment: Many websites display statistics of donations/contributions they receive through Paypal or similar systems, so what you want should be possible to do without complex Forex set-ups.

Comment: it would depend on what you are and what the project is. Each of the sites have requirements: charity or not, established business or not; making an app or not;...

Comment: Agree on an independent auditor.

Comment: Didn't we have a very similar question a few days ago? Ah yes, [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66887/is-there-any-kind-type-of-bank-accounts-that-does-not-show-me-the-transaction-hi#comment104893_66887) it is.

Comment: @mkennedy C'mon and vote my question as off-topic.

Comment: It's borderline because it's not 'personal finance'! I was just pointing out a neat- duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't one of the existing crowdsourcing systems meet your needs? Yes, they charge a commission, but they have already addressed the issues you raise and specifically they provide the third-party accounting you want.

Comment: Ok. Sites like GoFundMe.com show the contributors list with name and amount.

Comment: The established crowd sourcing option also gives you some built-in protection against violating SEC rules if you're in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than automating it, why not just create a listing that you maintain and display on your site yourself?  That way you don't have to give out credentials or anything else.

It also presents a bit of a marketing opportunity.  You could group contributors by the size of their contributions and thank them publicly.  For example, maybe your top contributors could be members of the "Heroes Club", and you could come up with jazzy names for other groups.  It's a way of publicly acknowledging their contributions in a way that they appreciate, and perhaps it motivates others to up their own contributions to get into one of the more prominent groupings.  It becomes a competitive "one-upsmanship" thing, if that makes sense.

I understand your desire to be transparent, and that's admirable, but see the marketing and public relations opportunity it brings to you as well.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: I've definitely seen this done before (seems popular in museums and the like), but I don't think it fits the requirement of "must be completely transparent, public, operated by a third-party (can't be cooked up)". From a skeptic's point of view, it's not trustworthy because you're still just taking OP's word that so-and-so really did donate that amount. But if that's not a major concern, this could be a good strategy.

Comment: The only way you can overcome the "transparency" aspect would be to have the information audited and verified by a third-party firm (like an accounting firm), in which case you'd have to provide the proof of their audit (they usually provide a statement).  That's one way, and it still leaves the rest of my suggestion intact.